# What was the original Runescape 'Customization' music?

Tags: oldschool-runescape, game-music-identification

It was before a few overhauls of Runescape, and it played when you clicked on character customization (the little red closet booth would come out).

It was a really peaceful and happy music, I think I even remember birds chirping in the background. I can't seem to find it anywhere!

Does anyone know what I'm talking about? Does anyone know the clip name?

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a specific music clip for customising your character, but there is one called 'Newbie Melody' that played in the tutorial section:

Comment: If this isn't it, try looking through [OldScapeMusic's Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/OldScapeMusic/videos), it's possible you'll find it there.